# How to restart the Python script automatically if it is frozen/stopped?

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation

I am running my Python script in the background which is web-scraping data tables with an infinity loop, but sometimes if there is an internet connection problem or other little error like freeze, my program and the script are stopping.

How can I avoid this error to get an acceptable automation?
(I don't want to use cmd or task scheduler, i want to solve this problem inside my python script)

Comment: Where exactly in your script is it freezing? Additional info about it's behavior would help

Comment: If a website cant loading (webdriver) in my program is stopping, and cant go on

Comment: stopping how? throwing an exception? crashing? freezing?

Comment: stopping without any error, any exception, just cant continue this procedure, that's why i am a little bit confused now

Comment: if you hit ctrl+C, what is the stack trace being displayed?

Comment: if i hit ctrl+c i just close the window (geckodriver.exe)